# Converting site form tables to divs

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get some hands-on learning of divs. I'm converting a site from tables to divs and am laying out the site before filling it in. Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DAM7K/

Basically what I want the site to do is stay centered whenever I expand or contract a browser window (pretty basic). I can't get the `right_box` to go inline with the `body_box`. I tried to place the `right_box` by using `top:` and `left:` and `position:absolute` in my CSS but when I decided to use `<div align="center">` for the whole layout (to keep it all centered), the `right_box` obviously didn't stay in place in relation to the other elements.

I know it's a pretty basic question, I'm just confusing myself right now. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified example of what I think you are trying to do.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>  
    <div class="sidebar"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{width:400px; height:500px; margin:0 auto; background:lightgray;}
.content{width:200px; float:left; height:200px; background:salmon;}
.sidebar{width:200px; float:left; height:500px; background:lightblue;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B5hRZ/)

Here is your example, [fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/DAM7K/8/).

```
#body_box{
    ...
    width:750px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    }

#right_box{
    width:246px; /* Not 250px because your borders add another 4px */
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    }
```

Comment: Ok yeah yeah. I actually also tried adding position:absolute and float:left to the body_box and then position:absolute and float:right to the right_box and that worked too. I guess long story short I need to learn floats better! Thanks!

Comment: Floating `#right_box` right works too, but `position:absolute;` is not necessary in that situation.

Comment: True. Yeah I just realized that was a mistake (I had other code in there). Basically float:left and float:right worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/DAM7K/10/ and see comment explanations below.

```
#CompleteLayout{
    width:1000px;
    height:1100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto; /* this centers it */
    overflow: auto; /* this clears the floats I added */
    }

#header{
    height:207px;
    width:998px; /* this needed to downsize for border */
    border:1px solid blue;
    }

#top_image{
    width:998px; /* this needed to downsize for border */
    height:167px;
    border:1px dotted #993300;
    }

#navbar{
    width:998px; /* this needed to downsize for border */
    height:40px;
    border:1px dotted #990000;
    }

#slideshow{
    width:998px; /* this needed to downsize for border */
    height:200px;
    border:1px dotted #990000;
    }

#body_box{
    height:686px;
    width:750px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float: left; /* added this to get right_box to sit beside */
    }

#right_box{
    height:686px;
    width:246px;  /* this needed to downsize for borders of this and body_box  */
    border:1px solid black;
    float: left; /* added this to get right_box to sit beside */
    }
```